# Convert a Field format before Where Statement in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace, converters, where-clause

I am building a calendar in asp that is database populated using aspwebcalender. Problem is my database date format is mm-dd-yyyy (startdate field) and aspwebcalender is looking for mm/dd/yyyy (DateToUse value). I am trying to convert the field on the fly in my WHERE statement. I have tried the REPLACE, CONVERT and even parsing and rebuilding the field. Im sure there is some simple solution.

This is what I have so far for my field [startdate]:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
 WHERE (SELECT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startdate, 101) 
         AS [MM/DD/YYYY])) = #" & DateToUse & "# ORDER BY StartTime"
```

I know its a mess.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE  
  (Left((startdate),2)) + '/' + MID(startdate,4,2)+ '/' + right(startdate,4)) = " & 
      DateToUse & " ORDER BY StartTime"
```

and also:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
      (REPLACE(startdate,-,/)) = #" & DateToUse & "# ORDER BY StartTime"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If startdate is a date Type and oracle database.

then use this one :

```
 select to_char(StartTime, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), "OTHER COLUMNS to select" FROM customers WHERE 
  to_char(StartTime, 'mm/dd/yyyy ') = DateToUse  ORDER BY StartTime desc;
```

Comment: Undefined function 'to_char' in expression.  Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Im using an access 2003 .mdb database

Comment: For access, replace by format(StartTime, 'mm/dd/yyyy').